# split string column in the brackets that contain only 4 digits and place those 4 digits in a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset,

```py
pandas_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'movie': ['Discreet Charm of the Bourgeoisie, The (Charme discret de la bourgeoisie, Le) (1998)',
                                           'Attack Force Z (a.k.a. The Z Men) (Z-tzu te kung tui) (2001)',
                                           'State of Things, The (Stand der Dinge, Der) (2005)',
                                           'Happy Tour, A (2002)',
                                           'Awfully Big Adventure, An (2008)',
                                           'American President, The (2010)'],
                                 'genre': ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Children', 'Action', 'Documentary']})
pandas_dataframe
```

An I want to split the year of publication (xxxx) into a separate column called "year", so my final output to look like this,

```py
pandas_dataframe_new = pd.DataFrame({'movie': ['Discreet Charm of the Bourgeoisie, The (Charme discret de la bourgeoisie, Le)',
                                           'Attack Force Z (a.k.a. The Z Men) (Z-tzu te kung tui)',
                                           'State of Things, The (Stand der Dinge, Der)',
                                           'Happy Tour, A',
                                           'Awfully Big Adventure, An',
                                           'American President, The'],
                                 'genre': ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Children', 'Action', 'Documentary'],
                                 'year': ['1998', '2001', '2005', '2002', '2008', '2010']})
pandas_dataframe_new
```

Comment: simple reg expression `pandas_dataframe["year"] = pandas_dataframe.movie.str.extract("([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])")`

Comment: @RobRaymond thanks for your answer. It's marked as duplicate and actually the duplicate question sufficed as an answer.

Comment: `df.assign(**df['movie'].str.extract('(?P<movie>.*)\((?P<year>\d{4})\)'))` You can try this too.